# NumPy eliminate double loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How can I vectorize this code snippet and eliminate this double loop? Even with "only" 1001 elements in `a` this takes almost 30s.

```
a = np.linspace(-.5, .5, 1001)
S = np.zeros((a.size, a.size))

# east, north and tp are np.arrays of equal length
for l, sy in enumerate(a):
    for k, sx in enumerate(a):
            S[l,k] = np.sum((east*sx + north*sy - tp)**2)
```

Comment: To make this question more useful for future users, could you edit the title and description to be more descriptive of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please see this [discussion on vectorization requests](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/are-vectorization-requests-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
S = np.sum((east*a[:, None, None] + north*a[:, None] - tp)**2, axis=-1)
```

But if the `east` `north` and `tp` arrays are large it may actually perform worse, as it avoids looping but creates an intermediate array of `a.size**2 * east.size` items.

If you expand your expression, you could also do:

```
e2 = np.dot(east, east)
n2 = np.dot(north, north)
t2 = np.dot(tp, tp)
en = np.dot(east, north)
et = np.dot(east, tp)
nt = np.dot(north, tp)

a2 = a*a

S = (e2*a2[:, None, None] + b2*a2[:, None] + t2 +
     2*en*a[:, None, None]*a[:, None] - 2*et*a[:, None, None] -
     2*nt*a[:, None])
```

which should give the same result without the ginormous intermediate array.